# How to watch for Vue instance property inside component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a plugin that adds some property to Vue instance.
Then I can access this property inside components using `this.$plugin.prop`. How can I watch for its changes? I need to do something inside component based on `this.$plugin.prop` value but neither `watch` or `this.$watch` worked for me. I assume its because `watch` works in component context so I can't watch for variable outside component, for example

```
    mounted() {
        this.$watch('$plugin.prop', val => console.log(val));
    }
```

doesn't work.
What is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try to store plugin prop reference in data model of component, and then watch that property from the component data model - http://jsbin.com/kopucayoro/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `mounted()` try

```
watch: {
   '$plugin.prop': function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }
}
```

The offical documentation on watchers in the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Answer (score 0):

You may use computed properties instead like so:

```
computed: {
    pluginChanged() {
        console.log(this.$plugin.prop.val);
        return this.$plugin.prop.val;
    }
```

Read more about computed properties [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Comment: I don't know but it doesn't work with data outside of component for me either. Works with data inside component tho.

Comment: Depends on how you designed that custom `plugin`! Did you use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)? If no, then you should consider that Vue only watches `data` option. In other word, only `data` model is reactive. As mentioned before you may use `Vuex` library or store that data in your component's `data` model. @MaxStern

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense, I missed this part about only `data` being reactive.